# Allowing Javascript and CSS files to be crawled

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Does this block or allow Google bot access?

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Allow: /*.js*

Allow: /*.css*
```

Anybody knows above robots.txt format is blocking or allowing Google Bot access?

Answer (score 8):

Your rules would work, but probably the simplest form of allow rule to allow crawling javascript and css resources:

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Allow: .js
Allow: .css
```

This will allow anything like `https://example.com/deep/style.css?something=1` or `https://example.com/deep/javascript.js`, and leaves no much space for interpretation for other search engines.
If however you have a disallow rule that's more specific than the blanket allow rules, then that will take precedence. For example if you have:

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /deep/
Allow: .js
Allow: .css
```

Then the allow rules won't work, because the `https://example.com/deep/javascript.js` (but would for `https://example.com/javascript.js`). To allow the JS and CSS file in the generally disallowed directory, you would do:

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /deep/
Allow: /deep/*.js
Allow: /deep/*.css
```

Once you have this, you can test your setup in Search Console - Blocked resources feature.

Comment: Thanks Methode for Quick Reply. 

But that i am using.. is it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: no, it's not wrong, it's just confusing and overloaded so some search engines might misinterpret it. please upvote and/or accept the answer if it works

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks Methode. 

Very Helpful.

Comment: Surely this only 'works' because there is no Disallow: rules. If there was a disallow rule, it would take effect. These Allows: would **need** a * at the start to have any effect, right now are placebos only :) I I tested this in the Search Console. `Allow: .js` never fired, but `Allow: *.js` did. (the Allow also needs to be longer than the Disallow) http://imgur.com/9CJJ8Ww,RbcwxD2,utemQol#1

Answer (score 0):

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Allow: .js
Allow: .css
```

Those rules will only Allow: the following URLs...

```
website.com/.jswebpage.html
website.com/.csswebpage.html
```

The best way to unblock JS and CSS files would be to either unblock the holding categories or use the full Allow: path to the holding directory, such as...

```
Allow: /assets/*.js
Allow: /assets/*.css
```

The above example assumes the js and css files are held in /assets/.

Also to note...

If you had the following in your robots.txt file...

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /cat1/
Disallow: /cat2/
Disallow: /cat3/
Allow: /assets/*.js
Allow: /assets/*.css

User-Agent: Googlebot
Allow: /assets/*.js
Allow: /assets/*.css
```

Google will skip the wildcard entries in full and only take note of what is actually under the user-agent Googlebot. So it's best to try not to use the useragent Googlebot in robots unless you absolutely have to. And if you do then add all the pages/assets that they need to take note of, even if they are duplicated with the wildcard entries.